# Password generator project in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

A few days ago I posted my password generator project to help me learn and become more comfortable. I got a lot of great replies from that and I've sense updated and would love another look at the program.

I've made it so that I can import it and use it to generator a password. I've also added support for completely custom subsets of characters.

Throw any suggests or comments you have! Anything is welcome.

```
import string
from string import ascii_lowercase
from string import ascii_uppercase
from string import digits as numeric
from string import punctuation
import secrets
import argparse
from argparse import HelpFormatter

def generate_characters(character_set, character_amount):
    for _ in range(0, character_amount):
        yield secrets.choice(character_set)

def shuffle(input_str):
    output = ""
    for _ in range(0, len(input_str)):
        index = secrets.randbelow(len(input_str))
        output += "".join(input_str[index])
        input_str = "".join([input_str[:index], input_str[index + 1 :]])
    return output

def generate_password(password_length,
                      subset_lowercase=ascii_lowercase, subset_uppercase=ascii_uppercase,
                      subset_numeric=numeric, subset_special="!@#$%^&*",
                      min_lowercase=1, min_uppercase=1,
                      min_numeric=1, min_special=1):
    superset = "".join([subset_lowercase, subset_uppercase, subset_numeric, subset_special])
    password = "".join(generate_characters(subset_lowercase, min_lowercase))
    password += "".join(generate_characters(subset_uppercase, min_uppercase))
    password += "".join(generate_characters(subset_numeric, min_numeric))
    password += "".join(generate_characters(subset_special, min_special))
    password += "".join(generate_characters(superset, password_length-len(password)))
    return shuffle(password)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        formatter_class=HelpFormatter,
        description="Generates a password",
        usage="")

    parser.add_argument(
        "-len",
        "--length",
        type=int,
        default=24,
        dest="password_length",
        help="Length of the generated password")
    parser.add_argument(
        "-lc",
        "--lower",
        type=int,
        default=1,
        dest="min_lowercase",
        help="Minimum number of lowercase alpha characters")
    parser.add_argument(
        "-uc",
        "--upper",
        type=int,
        default=1,
        dest="min_uppercase",
        help="Minimum number of uppercase alpha characters")
    parser.add_argument(
        "-num",
        "--numeric",
        type=int,
        default=1,
        dest="min_numeric",
        help="Minimum number of numeric characters")
    parser.add_argument(
        "-sp",
        "--special",
        type=int,
        default=1,
        dest="min_special",
        help="Minimum number of special characters")
    parser.add_argument(
        "-ext",
        "--extended",
        action="store_const",
        default=False,
        const=True,
        dest="special_extended",
        help="Toggles the extended special character subset. Passwords may not be accepted by all services")
    parser.add_argument(
        "-sl",
        "--subset_lower",
        type=str,
        default=ascii_lowercase,
        dest="subset_lower",
        help="Allows for a custom subset of lowercase characters")
    parser.add_argument(
        "-su",
        "--subset_upper",
        type=str,
        default=ascii_uppercase,
        dest="subset_upper",
        help="Allows for a custom subset of uppercase characters")
    parser.add_argument(
        "-sn",
        "--subset_numeric",
        type=str,
        default=numeric,
        dest="subset_numeric",
        help="Allows for a custom subset of numeric characters")
    parser.add_argument(
        "-ss",
        "--subset_special",
        default="",
        type=str,
        dest="subset_special",
        help="Allows for a custom subset of special characters")

    args = parser.parse_args()

    if args.subset_special:
        special = args.subset_special
    elif args.special_extended:
        special = punctuation
    else:
        special = "!@#$%^&*"

    generated_password = generate_password(
        args.password_length,
        args.subset_lower,
        args.subset_upper,
        args.subset_numeric,
        special,
        args.min_lowercase,
        args.min_uppercase,
        args.min_numeric,
        args.min_special,
    )

    print("Password:", generated_password)
```

Comment: talking about the code it is pretty well-written and formatted, good job!.

Comment: Can you link your older code here? I want to understand what secrets is doing.

Comment: @VisheshMangla [The secrets module is used for generating cryptographically strong random numbers suitable for managing data such as passwords, account authentication, security tokens, and related secrets.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html). Available in stdlib since v3.6

Answer (score 1):

- You have a lot of inconsistencies.

  - `import string` `from string import ...` But then only using `import secrets`.

    I would only use `import string`.
  - You do `[:index]` but also `[index + 1 :]`.
  - You do `index + 1` but you also do `password_length-len(password)`.
  - You start `generate_password` using a one argument per line style, and then don't for the rest of the arguments.
- You should move `"!@#$%^&*"` into a constant, as you've duplicated it.
- You can use [`random.SystemRandom.choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) rather than `generate_characters`. [`SystemRandom`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.SystemRandom) uses [`os.urandom`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.urandom) which is "suitable for cryptographic use."

  ```py
  import random

  srandom = random.SystemRandom()


  def generate_characters(character_set, character_amount):
      return srandom.choices(character_set, k=character_amount)
  ```
- You can use [`random.SystemRandom.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/random.html#random.sample) to replace `shuffle`.
- Your current method is really inefficent it runs in \$O(n^2)\$ time.
  As you're building a new list every iteration.

  ```py
  "".join([input_str[:index], input_str[index + 1 :]])
  ```

  Instead change `input_str` to a list and use a similar algorithm by swapping the current index with the selected. Also known as the [Fisher–Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

  ```py
  def shuffle(input_str):
      output = list(input_str)
      for i in range(len(input_str)):
          index = srandom.randrange(i, len(input_str))
          output[i], output[index] = output[index], output[i]
      return "".join(output)
  ```
- I'm not a fan of passing so many keyword arguments to `generate_password`.
  I would instead make it take tuples of (subset, amount) and build the password that way.

  You can loop over these arguments so that the code is simple too.

  ```py
  def generate_password(password_length, *subsets):
      password = "".join(
          generate_characters(subset, minimum)
          for subset, minimum in subsets
      )
      superset = "".join(subset for subset, _ in subsets)
      password += "".join(generate_characters(superset, password_length - len(password)))
      return shuffle(password)
  ```

---

**Suggested code**

```py
import string
import random
import argparse

srandom = random.SystemRandom()


def generate_password(password_length, *subsets):
    password = "".join(
        "".join(srandom.choices(subset, k=minimum))
        for subset, minimum in subsets
    )
    superset = "".join(subset for subset, _ in subsets)
    password += "".join(srandom.choices(superset, k=password_length - len(password)))
    return "".join(srandom.sample(password, len(password)))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ...

    generated_password = generate_password(
        args.password_length,
        (args.subset_lower, args.min_lowercase),
        (args.subset_upper, args.min_uppercase),
        (args.subset_numeric, args.min_numeric),
        (special, args.min_special),
    )
    print("Password:", generated_password)
```

Comment: Is srandom.choices different from random.choices?

Comment: @VisheshMangla Yes, please read the description accompanying the code as it will explain how it is and why it is fine.

Comment: ok, thanks for the info.